# XSLT: Understanding context of position() within 'match' predicate

Tags: xslt, xpath

It seems that the `position()` value within `<xsl:template match` is not the same as within the template. Here is an example (can be also be viewed [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXB)):

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<section>
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <h1>Header <i>2</i></h1>
</section>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
   <xsl:template match="section">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="h1[i]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="h1[position() ne 1 and position() eq last()]">
        <h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </h1>
        <dev>
            cond: <xsl:value-of select="position() ne 1 and position() eq last()"/>
        </dev>
        <dev>pos: <xsl:value-of select="position()"/></dev>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Header 2</h1>
      <dev>
         cond: false
      </dev>
      <dev>pos: 1</dev>
   </body>
</html>
```

The same condition within the match predicate, evaluates to true within the template. The `position()` value is `1` as expected within the template, but seems to have a different value in the match predicate. Can someone help me understand this, please? How can I avoid match the second h1 with the same conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a match pattern, you can only use `position()` within a predicate, and it then refers to the position of a node within the sequence of things tested by the predicate. This will always depend only on the position of the node within the containing tree (usually, its position relative to its siblings).

As a free-standing XPath expression, `position()` refers to the position of a node within the sequence of nodes being processed by the current call on (typically) `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates`. This has no necessary relationship to the position of the node in its containing tree.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to look at the spec, for the `position()` function that is https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-position and says

> Returns the context position from the dynamic context. (See Section
> C.2 Dynamic Context Components XP31.)

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-xp-evaluation-context-components says "Context position  dynamic; changes during evaluation of path expressions and predicates".

Furthermore, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#focus explains that instructions like `apply-templates` or `for-each` change the focus consisting of context item, context position and context size.

So based on that it shouldn't come as a surprise that `position()` inside a predicate of a match pattern and inside of a template body are not giving the same value.

Pattern matching is explained in detail in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#patterns with examples like "`para[1]` matches any `para` element that is the first `para` child element of its parent." should make that clear.

The further text than says "The formal definition, however, is useful for understanding the meaning of a pattern such as `para[1]`. This matches any node selected by the expression `root(.)//(child-or-top::para[1])`: that is, any para element that is the first para child of its parent, or a para element that has no parent.".

Comment: Thank you for specs. It helps to get the broader picture. What I still can't wrap my head around though, is why the position in the predicate is 2 (confirmed that it's 2 by adding 'position ne 2' predicate). As you've said " instructions like apply-templates or for-each change the focus." So why hasn't the focus changed in this case? Since I specifically applied "h1[i]" ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pattern matching happens before any template is executed, pattern matching is not subjected to the focus change that happens on execution inside of a template body. You might want to read up on an introduction to the XSLT processing model, it is hard to do that in a stackoverflow post but several books exist, a free PDF version of an introduction to XSLT and XPath 2 is listed in the info section of the xslt tag.

Comment: Here is a link to the book: https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I appreciate the pointer!